# image does not fetch from database php pdo

Tags: php, database, image, pdo, blob

Here, i'm trying to fetch the image from database. In my database i can see a image file size (`[BLOB - 62.3  KiB]`). But, it didn't work. i didn't get any error here. i'm confused where i made a mistake here?

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM ebusers');
        $conn->errorInfo();
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {   
            echo '<img class=shadow_img width=160 height=180 src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['UserProfilePicture']) . '"/>';
            echo $row['Address'];
            echo "<br>";echo "<br>";echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        'Error : '.$e->getMesssage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: what do you get in `base64_encode($row['UserProfilePicture']) `?

Comment: it shows empty page.. when i tried `var_dump(base64_encode($row['UserProfilePicture']))` i can get the values like this `wwEEpGSUZcMAECAVwwSFwwSFwwXDD/7lwwDkFkb2JlXDBkgFwwXDBcMAH/21wwhFwwCAYGBgYGCAYGCAwIBwgMDgoICAoOEA`

Comment: Column name are matched `UserProfilePicture`  `echo $row['UserProfilePicture'];` ?

Comment: @KrishR : i'm sure. both names are same...

Comment: If you really only get a blank page, there something wrong PHP-side. Are you sure that there are no syntax error in your script or in the included one?

Comment: i didn't get any syntax error.. i'm very confused to solve this one...

Comment: Look, if you get a totally empty page, how did you do the var_dump()?

Comment: `var_dump(base64_encode($row['UserProfilePicture']))` returns like this `EEpGSUZcMAECAVwwSFwwSFwwXDD/7lwwDkFkb2JlXDBkgFwwXDBcMAH/21wwhFwwCAYGBgYGCAYGCAwIBwgMDgoICAoOEA0NDg`

Comment: I mean, where did you put that `var_dump()` in your script? If it's in the while loop and that outputs something, I would expect the `echo`s to output something too.

Comment: yes i used inside the while loop. i tried echo and print_r... same result like above ...

Comment: If you had var_dump(...) and echo '<img.../>' in the same loop, they both had to write something, and so the page wasn't empty. What did that img tag look like? Didn't it output a broken image, at least? What about the two other echos in the loop?

Comment: i can see a broken img.. like this http://postimg.org/image/6t242vw55/